# Is built PREEMPT_RT more pre-emptive than PREEMPT_DYNAMIC set on full?

Tags: linux-kernel, preempt-rt

I am curious if there is any difference functional wise of the pre-empting system between the the modes described in the title.
I was looking at this page https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/Kconfig.preempt and ca't say for sure if there is a difference or not.

This article https://lwn.net/Articles/944686/ seems to suggest there is no difference...

How to tell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems pretty clear to me if you take a closer look at the article and kernel config options you link:

- There are 4 "levels" of kernel preemptiveness possible: `PREEMPT_NONE`, `PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY`, `PREEMPT` (full) and `PREEMPT_RT` (real-time).
- The last one (`PREEMPT_RT`) is the most aggressive and requires changes to kernel code that are only possible at build time.
- The `PREEMPT_DYNAMIC` configuration option makes it possible to select among the first 3 levels (none, voluntary and full) at boot time through the kernel command line.
- `PREEMPT_DYNAMIC` is not compatible with `PREEMPT_RT`, because the latter requires substantial build time changes to kernel code.

Therefore, running a kernel with `PREEMPT_DYNAMIC` set to full is roughly the same as running a kernel built with `PREEMPT=y`. `PREEMPT_RT` is more preemptive than "full" `PREEMPT`, but not available with `PREEMPT_DYNAMIC`.